# Failed to write csv files to Proficy Historian 5.0

Tags: csv, historian, proficy

I was able to import the csv files containing the tags for the data collector of the proficy historian 5.0. However, every time I tried to import data formatted in csv, it always failed and the error was "Error adding value [OUTSIDE ARCHIVE ACTIVE HOURS, -12]". I doubt this issue comes from wrong formatting of the CSV file and I'm guessing if I change some setting of the historian, it could be fixed. Am I on the right track here? Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Propably Proficy Historian isn't letting you to write data to a read-only section. You should increase the archive parameter ***Data is Read-only after***.  Its a parameter  of hours, prior to now, for which data can be stored in a read/write archive. After the time expires, that portion of the archive file is automatically made read-only. Incoming data values with timestamps prior to this time are rejected. A single archive file, therefore, may have a portion made read-only, another portion that is read/write containing recently written data, and another that is unused free space.

The simplest way to change the *Data is Read-only After (Hours)* is to run the Proficy Historian Administrator, click *Data Stores* then *Data Stores Options* and then increase the number of *Data is Read-only After (Hours)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did check the setting and tested it with a piece of data with the latest timestamp. It still didn't work and the error message still remains the same. Below is the complete error message                         zAddValue>>Error Adding Value[Outside Archive Active Hours,-12]                          writeRecordset>>Error Adding Value: Test_Tag.F_CV,20160526063000000000